# Pydub playback from queue

Tags: python, audio, audio-streaming, playback, pydub

I'm working with audio processing for my program and need to implement a simple monitor playback.

To do "realtime" processing all pydub.AudioSegments are sliced into 20ms chunks before they are sent down the machinery.
At the end the segments sent to a simple `deque`  that is contentiously being filled with 20ms `pydub.AudioSegment` untill it has 300ms worth.

```py
    @tasks.loop(seconds=0.01)
    async def fill(self):
        if source is None:
            print("NOPE")
            return
        if len(deque) < size:
            try:
                segment = next(self.source.audio_segment_generator
                deque.append(segment)
            except StopIteration:
                print("source depleted")
```

The `deque` is being pop'ed to a discord bot that expects 20ms audio worth of bytes.

Everything works flawlessly, however I also need  a simple local playback that can if needed play audio directly to speakers.

Something like this:
also assume its running on its own thread:

```py
from pydub.playback import play

def play_from_deque(deque):
    while True:
    if is_playing_monitor: 
      play(deque.pop())
```

I wrote a quick simple test to see it the `pydub.play()` would work being called repeatedly on 20ms segments:

```py
mp3 = requests.get("http://www.hochmuth.com/mp3/Haydn_Adagio.mp3")
segment = AudioSegment.from_file(io.BytesIO(mp3.content), format='mp3').set_frame_rate(40800)
sliced_segments = segment[::20]

for slice in sliced_segments:
    play(slice)
```

But audio got really choppy and barely recognizable.

After some googling someone mentioned `import sounddevice as sd`, but so far I have not been able to make it work.
The raw bytes can be accessed with `segment.raw_data` so audio could be played from bytes as well.

Any tips or python libraries I should look into?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out myself, here is code if anyone has a similar problem:

I got it working with:

```py
import io
import requests

import pyaudio
from pydub import AudioSegment

mp3 = requests.get("http://www.hochmuth.com/mp3/Haydn_Adagio.mp3")
segment = AudioSegment.from_file(io.BytesIO(mp3.content), format='mp3').set_frame_rate(40800)
sliced_segments = segment[::20]

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(segment.sample_width),
                channels=segment.channels,
                rate=segment.frame_rate,
                output=True)

while True:
    try:
        for slice in sliced_segments:
            stream.write(slice.raw_data)
    finally:
        stream.stop_stream()
        stream.close()

        p.terminate()
```